# curl doesn't work - it always connects to static ip (10.151.34.14) in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to create simple code for crawl using curl.. my code like this.. 
but it's still route to static ip 10.151.34.14... i change my url.. but it's still to 10.151.34.14.

```
    <?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://aampuh.blogspot.co.id/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "foo");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
echo curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl))
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxXbM.png)

this is my output... please help me... i'm so confuse until now.

Comment: Could be a caching issue on the client side, so that your browser shows the cached result of your first try. Try a deep reload and watch the access log files of your http server.

Comment: Is the server behind a proxy or something?

Comment: what does `ping http://aampuh.blogspot.co.id` return?

Comment: I think you mean `ping aampuh.blogspot.co.id`.

Answer (score 1):

It seams there is a proxy configured in your environment.

```
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
```

Those are often defined in environment variables, see print_r($_ENV) for details.